# How to make a glass scratch in shader nodes

Tags: shader-nodes

As seen below, I would like to create a scratch where I am using normal maps to create this effect where the scratch has happened.

What I have done for now is making a mask that only focuses on the scratch area, but for making the effect, I have only come up with using a voronoi texture that I then connect to a bump map.

[image]

Comment: Hello it's not clear what you want to do with this texture, if you plug it into the Bump node it doesn't give the desired effect? Also what do you want to do with Voronoi, combine it with the scratch?

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. I didn´t make it clear, but I want to recreate a scratch procedurally so I can do many variations to my object.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**For more variations**:

In 'B' you can add a Math node set it to 'Add' and check clamp and duplicate every node in 'A' connect it to the Math node (Now you have 2 'A's connect each one of them to a value in the Math node play with the voronoi's textures in the second 'A' for more variations